# How can I disable the responsive behaviour in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How can I disable the responsive behaviour in Bootstrap 4, while maintaining the styles? I want users that access the website in the mobile phone to have the same website as the desktop version and zoom in and zoom out with finger gestures. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Bootstrap is not really made to be unresponsive, you can achieve something like that by altering the viewport meta-tag.

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.1">`

This will set the initial scale at 10% of the original scale.

Also see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#translate-meta-to-at-viewport for more.

Comment: For me I still need to add:
`.container, .container-fluid {
    /* Set width to your desired site width */
    min-width: 1170px;
}`
to achieve non-responsive when device's screen shrinking.

Comment: Unfortunately only works for mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

so i would suggest that you just put everything in the bootstrap grid and design it for mobile view only. so instead of using multiple classes for multiple screen sizes like "col-4 col-md-3" or flexible like "col" just use "col-n" classes only, so on mobile it'll look like you want it to look (also you would have to zoom in and out if you place enough content in the cols because with col-n you tell bootstrap to use n/12 of the available width on smallest screen size and up) and on desktop it'll show its full beauty without the need to zoom. 
i hope this will help :)